# Long running PHP script using up server memory

Tags: php, api, laravel, memory-leaks

Bit of an odd one. I've got a Laravel 5 project which pulls data from an API and stores it in a local database. The third party API uses XML - I pull the data using Guzzle and parse it using SimpleXML objects.

I am trying to track down what appears to be a memory leak in this project. If the script is left running for long enough (and it will have to be - the first sync of the data could take a day or two) it consumes all the memory on, and eventually crashes, the server.

This is the confusing bit - I've run the app in debug mode and made it output memory_get_usage() periodically and stop after a given number of requests. PHP does NOT report a sharp increase. From start to finish the total memory usage reported this way increases by about 10kb. If I watch the process in Activity Monitor on my dev machine (a Mac), it goes from about 20mb to 30mb. I left a copy of the full script running overnight the other day and when I checked in the morning it claimed to have used 750mb.

The same thing happens on the Amazon EC2 instance where the script will do it's thing live. memory_get_usage() doesn't report anything unusual - but leave the script running and, in top, it will sit at the top of the process list and the MEM% will gradually increase until... bang. I've got a copy running right now - it started at about 7% and is now sat on 37.4%, but the amount of "free" memory isn't decreasing. It's using the buffers, I think.

So how do you track down an apparent memory leak when PHP doesn't believe it's got one?

Comment: You should be chunking that job up into smaller pieces, and push it onto the queue.

Comment: Laravel does have a que function, maybe you can take a look to that?

Comment: Don't you, by any chance, have Query Logging Enabled somewhere in your code `DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();`?

Comment: I'll look into queuing - if it's still executing the jobs in order wouldn't this still lead to a memory issue, though? @peterm, I've got query logging disabled in my code - although I think in Laravel 5 it's disabled by default anyway.

Comment: I ran this again last night - it made nearly 10,000 calls to the API and I was printing the memory_get_usage and memory_get_peak_usage() every few calls. 

At no point did either of the reported figures go over 12mb - but according to the process monitor my script (run as a httpd child process) was using nearer 100mb. Additionally, I have a PHP memory limit configured and I didn't run into this.

Where is this "extra" memory usage coming from if PHP can't measure it?